# Create Shortcut on desktop that calls PowerShell cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, desktop, shortcut, import-module

I' trying to create a shortcut on the desktop by C# code, that

1. opens PowerShell,
2. imports `myModule.dll`,
3. Clears the screen,
4. shows all my cmdlets of `myModule.dll`.

After executing C#, the shortcut appears on dektop, but for some reason quotes are set around the whole `shortcut.TargetPath`. After removing those quotes manually, everything is fine.

How do I prevent these quotes to be set?

My code:

```
object shDesktop = (object)"Desktop";
WshShell shell = new WshShell();
string shortcutAddress = (string)shell.SpecialFolders.Item(ref shDesktop) + @"\´MyModule.lnk";
IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
shortcut.Description = "MyModule";
shortcut.TargetPath = @"%Windir%\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -noexit -command &{ import-module \\srv\PS\MyModule.dll;clear; get-command -Module MyModule}";
shortcut.Save();
```

Comment: `shortcut.Arguments`

Comment: that's it. thx PetSerAl.

Answer (score 2):

As [commented by PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572409/c-create-shortcut-on-desktop-that-calls-powershell-cmdlet#comment68380451_40572409), use the `Arguments` property to pass arguments to the executable:

```
shortcut.TargetPath = @"%Windir%\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
shortcut.Arguments = @"-noexit -command &{ import-module \\srv\PS\MyModule.dll;clear; get-command -Module MyModule}";
```